# Do we have to open excel file EVERYTIME we write in it with Python?

Tags: python, excel, pyodbc, pywin32

I have to write on an Excel file using Python. I use win32com to do it.

I want to open it first do some stuff then write in my file do more stuff and write again in the file.

but I if I don't open the file everytime before writing, i have this error message:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2146827864, 'OLE error 0x800a01a8', None, None)

here my code :

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                'Server=SRVAKTCT-SQL\TCTSQL;'
                'Database=K;'
                'uid=Y;pwd=x')

cursor = connection.cursor()

for log, TA in zip(listeID,ListeTA):
    NomTA=TA[0]
    Equipe=TA[1]
    if log:

        #doing stuff
        results = something
        temps_log=results[0]
        print(temps_log)
        if temps_log is not None:
            temps_log=str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(temps_log)))

        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('//Srvaktct-bur02/Copie de vide.xlsx')
        ws=wb.Worksheets(date_onglet)
        ws.Cells(ligne_cumul,10).Value=temps_log
        #wb.Close(True)
    #wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('//Srvaktct-bur02/Copie de vide.xlsx')
    #ws=wb.Worksheets(date_onglet)
    ws.Cells(ligne_cumul,2).Value=NomTA
    ws.Cells(ligne_cumul,3).Value=Equipe

    wb.Close(True)
    excel.Application.Quit()
    ligne_cumul += 1
```

Here the code works only if I uncomment the comment region.

Comment: You're `Close` the workbook, and also `Quit` the application inside the loop. If you do this, of course you have to re-instantiate Excel, and re-open the workbook... See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I don't open the file everytime before writing, i have this error message:

Well yeah, because if you don't have a file object to write *to*, what else would you expect to happen?

You're doing a `wb.Close()` call within the loop, so, because you close it, you have to also re-open it if you want to write to it (or read from it) again. You're closing/opening the file twice witin the loop, and you're also doing the `excel.Quit` operation inside the loop, which requires that you re-instantiate it at each interation Better approach is to instantiate `excel` outside of the loop (and later `Quit` it after loop terminates).

Untested,but see if it will help (**revised because you mention it is the same file**)

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                'Server=SRVAKTCT-SQL\TCTSQL;'
                'Database=K;'
                'uid=Y;pwd=x')

cursor = connection.cursor()
wb, ws = None, None
filePath = '//Srvaktct-bur02/Copie de vide.xlsx'
# Get a handle on Excel application:
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
# Open the file outside of the loop, too:
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
ws=wb.Worksheets(date_onglet)
for log, TA in zip(listeID,ListeTA):
    NomTA=TA[0]
    Equipe=TA[1]
    if log:
        #doing stuff
        results = something
        temps_log=results[0]
        print(temps_log)
        if temps_log is not None:
            temps_log=str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(temps_log)))
            ws.Cells(ligne_cumul,10).Value=temps_log
    ws.Cells(ligne_cumul,2).Value=NomTA
    ws.Cells(ligne_cumul,3).Value=Equipe
    ligne_cumul += 1
# Don't close wb or Quit Excel inside the loop!
wb.Close(True)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! 
I did a mistake, it's in fact the same file ! sorry !

Comment: @amiraayadi I made some revisions to account for that. I still think you're duplicating some of your logic, and unnecessarily. I'll revise my answer for that, too...

Comment: When I started to write the code I did something like that ( I was careful to open before the loop and to close after the loop the file) but I saw that I not working with all Excel files ! With the file ".XLSM" for exemple I have to run my method if I want to write on it. Even with your answer it didn't work.

Here the Error message : pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Une exception s’est produite.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

Comment: Does the error only happen with `.XLSM` files (and not with `.XLSX` files?  If so, check your macro security settings in Excel, which may be preventing an XLSM macro-enabled file from opening.

Comment: It work fine with the .XLSX file. 
I can open the .XLSM file but only if I open it every time in the loop otherwise it's an Error message. 
Do you still think it is the macro security settings in Excel? even if i can open the xlsm file when i open it every loop ?

Comment: It does not make sense that you can open the file inside the loop (using exact same methods) but not outside of the loop. SVP [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38329760/edit) your question to show the code you currently implement, and the full traceback error from python;

Comment: i tried it 3 time i had the same error message ' Une exception s’est produite.' and i agree with you that make no sense! So I restart my computer and now it works!! thank you !!!

Comment: If a reboot solved the problem, then my guess is that you maybe had an orphaned Excel process which still had that workbook in an `Open` state. This might prevent you from opening the same file.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are opening the file every iteration of the loop.

You should move the lines

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('//Srvaktct-bur02/Copie de vide.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets(date_onglet)
```

to before the loop, so you don't need to close and re-open the file in every iteration.

Comment: OP will also need to uncomment the other lines (and assign to a *different* name than `wb` and `ws`), in order to write to the other file(s).

Comment: OP is also going to have potential problems attempting to open two files with same filename, in one instance of Excel application. Perhaps this is why the close/open within the loop.

Comment: I already tried to move it before the loop.
here the Error message : "pywintypes.com_error: (-2146827864, 'OLE error 0x800a01a8', None, None)"

I do it that way just because it did'nt work if i remove open it first.
But the exection time is very important and I don't have the time to open it every loop

Comment: @DavidZemens, Sorry my bad it is the same file here! i just forgot to change the file name